# Linux Mint - Remember window positions and sizes

Tags: linux, linux-mint, window-manager

Today I installed Linux Mint Mate in the default configuration and it has an annoying habit of forgetting window sizes and positions after they are closed. Everything gets reopened in the top left corner. I would like it to behave as Windows does, nothing fancy. Is there a solution?

Comment: Hi. If you think the below can be accepted as the answer, please do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets do a few things and see how it goes. Compiz is the window manager you have in mate desktop. Follow these steps.

1. Open Menu and search for 'startup programs'. Open it and create a new start up program with these details.

   ```
   Name: Compiz
   Command: compiz --replace --fast-filter
   Comment: OpenGL window and compositing manager
   ```
2. Under the startup programs make sure you enable the option that says `remember all processes running in next reboot`
3. There is a bug with Linux Mint mate that brings in a second window manager called 'marco' to work along which causes cpu spike. We have to disable it using these instructions.

Install the package 'mateconf-editor' via terminal using this command `sudo apt-get install mateconf-editor`. After installing type `mateconf-editor` in terminal. When the editor opens: Go to `/desktop/mate/session/required_components/windowmanager` and replace `"marco"` with `"compiz"`.

In the next reboot, if the cpu spike has not come down, we will just move the marco binary which will stop it from starting by default. Just open the terminal again and give this `sudo mv -f /usr/bin/marco /usr/bin/marco.bkp`

4. Under menu search for `'Compiz Config Settings Manager'` under which you can find all compiz-functions. Make sure you enable `'Window Decoration'`. You are free to give all fancy effects there.

Go for a reboot and this should help you.

Comment: Well I (mate13, 64, 4C, 6G), did as advised above and it worked without a hitch. But, compiz is still heavy on CPU (slightly less without marco loaded), pretty jerky too. And as to remembering windows positions, not very consistent either. Marco seems a much better solution, couldn't retrace my steps fast enough.

Comment: Great. I agree compiz is heavy and inconsistent but preferred than the others. I never got to replace and do a test with marco because it didn't enable out of the way via the options in LMDE 13.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem.  I am running MATE configured to look like Gnome 2.X, and my Window title bars were showing up underneath my upper panel!

Adding to the answer above, once Compiz is installed properly and configured to be your only window manager, go to the "Compiz Config Settings Manager" and make sure that under "Window Management" "Place Windows" is checkmarked and configured.  Click "Place Windows".  Under the "General" tab, you can change the placement mode.  Personally, I find 'Cascade' works very well for me.  Good luck!